# Pokemon dropped IV after evolving

Tags: pokemon-go

Is there a reason my perfect IV Poliwhirl dropped its IV after evolving to Politoad? It's IV went from 15-15-15 to 14-15-15.

Comment: If it went 15 to 14 then it's highly likely it was 14 from the beginning. It can easily be mistaken anyway. IVs won't drop by evolving AFAIK.

Answer (score 5):

No. IVs do not change on evolution. The only way for a Pokemon's IVs to change is upon trading it to another player, or upon purification.

What you are describing is almost certainly either a case of mistakenly evolving the wrong Poliwhirl, or simply misremembering its IVs.

If you have unlocked the Perfect Dex you can use that to check if you actually have a perfect Poliwhirl recorded. If not, you misremembered its IVs, but if you do you probably just evolved the wrong one.

Comment: The only time IVs don't change on purification is when the Pokemon is already 15/15/15, but you wouldn't want to be purifying a 100% anyways